# Include page numbers in Roman

Tags: formatting, page-numbering, roman-numerals

I am new to LaTeX. I am finding difficulty in display the page numbers in Roman numbers for VTU Certificate, certificate, declaration, acknowledgements, abbreviations, list of figures, list of tables.

I have given the sample tex code for the reference

```
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{epsfig}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amscd}

\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,extreport]

\begin{document}

\renewcommand\baselinestretch{1.2}
\baselineskip=18pt plus2pt


%\cleardoublepage
%\thispagestyle{plain}

\pagenumbering{roman}


\begin{romanpages}

    \thispagestyle{empty}


    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{VTU Certificate}
    \include{VTU_Certificate/vtu_certificate}

    \newpage    
    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Certificate from the Guide}
    \include{Certificate_from_the_Guide/certificate}


    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Declaration}%insert in contents
    \include{Declaration/declaration} %Decalaration page



%   \newpage %use for acknowledgment
    %\cleardoublepage

    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Acknowledgements} %insert in contents
    \include{Acknowledgement/acknowledgement} %acknowledgement page
    \normalsize{\tableofcontents} %list contents

    \thispagestyle{empty}   
    \pagestyle{empty}
    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Abbreviations}
    \include{Abbreviations/abbreviations} %acknowledgement page



    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{List of Figures} %insert in contents 
    \normalsize{\listoffigures} %list of figures
    %\cleardoublepage



    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{List of Tables}  %insert in contents
    \normalsize{\listoftables} %list of tables
    %\cleardoublepage


\end{romanpages} %end roman page numbering
```

Comment: What document class are you using?

Comment: this is my document class    \documentclass[12pt,a4paper,extreport]

Answer (score 1):

I am going to assume that the missing `\include` files contain `\chapter*`.

Every `\chapter` or `\chapter*` issues a `\clearpage` (or `\cleardoublepage`) and a `\thispagestyle{plain}`.  `\pagenumbering`and `\addcontentsline` should go after the `\clearpage`.  Fortunately, adding an extra `\clearpage` doesn't add an extra page.  `\thispagestyle{empty}` should go after `\chapter*` but before the end of the first page.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{extreport}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{epsfig}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amscd}
\usepackage{lipsum}% MWE only

\begin{document}

\renewcommand\baselinestretch{1.2}
\baselineskip=18pt plus2pt

%\begin{romanpages}

\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{VTU Certificate}%
\chapter*{VTU Certificate}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\pagenumbering{roman}
%\include{VTU_Certificate/vtu_certificate}

\clearpage
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Certificate from the Guide}%
\chapter*{Certificate from the Guide}
%\include{Certificate_from_the_Guide/certificate}

\clearpage
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Declaration}%insert in contents
\chapter*{Declaration}
%\include{Declaration/declaration} %Decalaration page

\clearpage
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Contents}%insert in contents
\normalsize{\tableofcontents} %list contents

\clearpage
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Abbreviations}
\chapter*{Abbreviations}
%\include{Abbreviations/abbreviations} %acknowledgement page

\clearpage
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{List of Figures} %insert in contents 
\normalsize{\listoffigures}% list of figures

\clearpage
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{List of Tables}  %insert in contents
\normalsize{\listoftables}% list of tables

\clearpage
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\chapter{First chapter}

\lipsum[1-6]
\end{document}
```

Comment: when i try to exectue the code i am getting footers which i have defined in the tex code. i dont want to have any footers except the page numbers should be displayed by using roman numbers.

Comment: i have used fancy header package for using header and footers. i want the page number to be displayed in roman only . i dont want the any other header and footer to be displayed. kindly help

Comment: The footers, headers, \pageref and the TOC all use \thepage.  You could use \arabic{page} with fancyhdr, but don't do it!

Comment: is there any way to include roman page numbers in the center of the footer without using \chapter command in latex. i am not able to get the contents of VTU Certificate . it is a blank page . kindly help me . Thank you in advance

Comment: At the moment I can't use MiKTeX at all.

Comment: Okay, MikTeX is working again (it was using `/bin/` instead of `\bin\ ` in some of the path names).  I would have to see the contents of the included file, if they are not using \chapter*.  Note that \cinclude also forces a new page, so it you cannot modify the contents, replace `\include{...}` with `\newpage\input{..}`..